# re sizing column data with tcl

Tags: for-loop, tcl

I have a set of data that has a X number of points and I want to re size this to x+n number of points.

I need to do this with tcl and am struggling in the last part.

I know the Max, Min and the delta that is needed to refit the data to desired number of points.

Original data:

```
-0.3925
-0.262
-0.1965
-0.026
-0.013
-0.0065
-0.0026
0
0.0026
0.0065
0.013
0.026
0.1965
0.262
0.3925
```

I'm struggling to construct a for loop that will, take the first value and subtract it from delta to create the second value. Subsequently take the second and subtract it from delta to create third and so on and so forth.

Given:

```
Points 19 
Min : -0.3925 
Max :0.3925 
Delta : 0.04361
```

Results column data would look like:

```
-0.3925
-0.348888889
-0.305277778
-0.261666667
-0.218055556
-0.174444444
-0.130833333
-0.087222222
-0.043611111
-6.93889E-17
0.043611111
0.087222222
0.130833333
0.174444444
0.218055556
0.261666667
0.305277778
0.348888889
0.3925
```

Could someone kindly give me some advice.

Comment: Any attempts so far? Also, could you give the value of delta so someone can test their script against the input to get the output?

Comment: Apologies, here is additional information:

Comment: Points 19
Min : -0.3925
Max :0.3925
Delta : 0.04361

Answer (score 1):

There are a few key points when doing this sort of thing (and these apply to languages other than Tcl too). Firstly, you should **compute the delta** from the span you want and the number of steps you want. Secondly, you should **keep your incrementing and loop control using integers** if you can, so as to avoid fencepost errors caused by rounding; instead **compute the value for the loop iteration** by multiplying the delta by the loop counter and adding to the originating value. Thirdly, you should consider what the right **precision** is when printing your results; in Tcl, this tends to mean using `format` with the `%f` conversion and appropriate width specifier.

```
set from -0.3925
set to 0.3925
set points 19

set delta [expr {($to-$from) / double($points-1)}]

for {set i 0} {$i<$points} {incr i} {
    set x [expr {$from + $i*$delta}]
    puts [format "%.5f" $x]
}
```

This produces this output:

```
-0.39250
-0.34889
-0.30528
-0.26167
-0.21806
-0.17444
-0.13083
-0.08722
-0.04361
0.00000
0.04361
0.08722
0.13083
0.17444
0.21806
0.26167
0.30528
0.34889
0.39250
```

Comment: Hi Donal, Thank you for the reply. I have done exactly the same in excel (without the for loop) and in Matlab it is a bit simpler (s = (min:delta:max)). In TCl I wasn't taking the product of $i and $delta. But this is very helpful.Thanks again